# How to properly create QUdpSocket on non-gui thread ? Readyread not emitted

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, qudpsocket

I'm writing a network library that wraps the `QUdpSocket`:

```
QAbstractSocket *UdpNetworkStreamer::addConnection()
{
    QUdpSocket *udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket->bind(connection.port, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    bool ret = udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress(connection.ip));
    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return udpSocket;
}
```

1. create a new `QUdpSocket`.
2. connect to its `readyRead` signal.
3. call `readDatagram` when `readyRead` is raised.

**All is working fine when I use the library from a Qt GUI application.**

The problem starts when another user includes the library used outside of a Qt GUI application.

He calls the `addConnection`  (which creates the socket and calls connect on the `readyRead`)

The thread on which the `addConnection` is called is non-Qt.

The `addConnection` seems to end successfully but the `readyRead` is never emitted.

Calling read (even though no `readyRead` was emitted) leads to a successful datagram read.

**Fixes that did not work :**

1. moving the the UDP socket thread to the this->thread

   ```
   QUdpSocket *udpSocket = new QUdpSocket();
   udpSocket->moveToThread(this->thread());
   udpSocket->setParent(this);
   ```
2. I tried to simulate the problem by calling:void

   ```
   MainWindow::on__btnOpenMulticastReceiver_clicked()
   {
      QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, 
      &MainWindow::CreateMulticastConnection, testHandle);
   }
   ```

   This also led to same symptoms as the one the user had with my library, meaning the `readyRead` wasn't emitted.
3. `QSignalSpy` - I've activated a spy on the `readyRead` signal; the counter kept on being zero although I could read data directly from the socket. The spy gave valid results (i.e. progressed) when used the socket was initialized on the main thread.

### My Questions:

1. What am I missing and doing wrong ?
2. What is the simplest way of having the `readyRead` emitted even though it is not created on the main GUI thread - I couldn't find any sample that works with no GUI or outside Qt threads.

Comment: Does the thread on which the user creates the `QUdpSocket` have an active event loop?  What happens in you alter the connection type to `Qt::DirectConnection` (just by way of a quick test)?

Comment: @G.M. tried to use direct connetion it didn't help. the thread that creates the udpsocket does not have an event loop, its not a qt thread.

Comment: If the thread on which the `UdpNetworkStreamer` exists doesn't have an event loop then queued signals can never be delivered to it.  I suspect the `readyRead` signal *is* being emitted but the resulting events are sitting in an event queue and will never be processed.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but wouldn't the signal spy counter be updated at least once ? it remains zero ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need an event loop for `readyRead` to be emitted. What would emit it, if there wasn't an event that would trigger it?

Comment: @thuga - i'd be happy to have an event loop that will process it ? how can you do it, if the calling thread does not have one ? create a new qthread and move the socket to that thread using moveToThread ?

Comment: You should see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801572/is-it-possible-to-create-local-event-loops-without-calling-qapplicationexec).

Comment: Are you creating a [`QCoreApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html) and calling `exec()` on it? The message loop that Qt dispatches on  won't run otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem this way :

```
void MainWindow::OpenConnection()
{
  QThread *t = new QThread();
  t->start();

  SocketWrapper *w= new SocketWrapper();

  w->moveToThread(t);

  w->metaObject()->invokeMethod(w, "CreateSocket", Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

You must call `invokeMethod()` with the thread the socket wrapper was `movedTo()` upon creation of the socket, so that the thread that creates the socket will have a running event loop.

In addition to that, the `CreateSocket()` needs to be a slot in the `SocketWrapper`, something like that :

```
class SocketWrapper : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit SocketWrapper(QObject *parent = 0);


signals:

public slots:
  void readyRead();
  void CreateSocket();
private:
  QUdpSocket *_socket;
};
```

Comment: You should be able to simply connect the thread's `started()` to your `CreateSocket()` - obviously don't start the thread until after the `moveToThread()` and `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to add `Q_OBJECT` macro to the beginning of the class from where you need to emit the signal. Unless you do this, the signal-slot mechanism will not function properly.

Comment: thanks but, i have that macro, Obviously since it is working perfectly when i use a qt gui applicationto use the library.